# How to get my emails delivered to the inbox instead of the spam folder?

Tags: php, email

I can try this:

```
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to         = 'email@email.com';//replace with your email

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

But some time get my `emails` delivered to the `spam`.

any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This have 2 reason in my look:

Some email service send mail to spam when:

- `from` header not equal by your `domain` for example your domain is
  `test.com` but from header is `support@google.com`.
- and your **server ip** in the black list in some server.

Comment: Thank for advice i can check as per your answer @Mahdi Parsa